# Grouping data from a .txt file in ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I was given a txt file with CGM readings with a date and timestamp that takes the reading every 5 mins. For day one there is 288 readings, I have to make 18 groups with 16 numbers in each group. How would I group them and add the CGM column.

Comment: I assume CGM here is continuous glucose monitoring.
To clarify: You want to create batches of 16 measurements in each. Do you want to then aggregate them? Or do you just want to 'group' them with an identifying variable?

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so we could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you just want to split your DF into 18 DF's: `dfs = np.array_split(df, 18)`